# What is the patina formed on copper pennies?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, home-experiment, metal

I'm currently taking high school chemistry and I don't quite understand my results from my experiment.

I had two pennies where both were put into a mixture of salt and vinegar. One of the pennies was dried and cleaned and the penny was like brand new. While the other penny Is left it in the mixture for 2 and 3 days with water.

[image]

Once I took it out, the penny had patina  forming. I'm not quite sure what type of reactions are occurring here and what elements/compounds are coming into play.

Comment: Do you know the years of the pennies?

Comment: Not really but why is that of any importance?

Comment: Pre-1982 pennies are 95% copper. Post-1982 pennies are 97.5% zinc. Zinc oxidizes more readily than copper, but with the 95% copper penny, that may not be an option, leading to copper "rust," i.e. oxidation.

Comment: The opposite may be true, though. If the zinc has no exposure to the oxidant inside the penny (new pennies are a copper shell around a zinc core), then the copper might have to oxidize, where the 95/5 Cu/Zn pennies may have been an alloy, allowing the zinc access to the oxidant.

Comment: Oh wow seems like you have profound knowledge on this. Let's assume the penny is very recent for this problem.

Comment: ...and in 1943 pennies were a zinc coated steel. Those actually do rust.

Comment: Maybe rust was a bad way of describing the surface of the penny. It looks like this: http://cdn2.buggyandbuddy.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Pice.jpg

Comment: Patina - that would be the right word.